# Code getting older references only locally

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

So, I am currently working on a project that uses Maven.

I added a spring-context dependency, on the latest version, and made sure to exclude any older spring references from other dependencies.

Seems like the code is getting an older reference still (even though it does not have a source attached anymore due to the old version of spring being excluded).

This issue is happening only on my local machine, as other people from the project downloaded the exact same code and didn't get this strage bean reference error.

Here's the pom.xml (I've erased internal project names)

I have tried running mvn clean install, checking dependencies with dependency:tree and nothing solves this problem.

````
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>---</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Project</name>

-<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
-<plugins>
-<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3</version>
-<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>


-<dependencies>
<!-- dependencies -->
-<dependency>
<groupId>---</groupId>
<artifactId>model</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>---</groupId>
<artifactId>general.dao</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>---</groupId>
<artifactId>ExternalJavaConfig</artifactId>
<version>1.0.9-RELEASE</version>
-<exclusions>
-<exclusion>
groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>---</groupId>
<artifactId>db</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
<version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>---</groupId>
<artifactId>---</artifactId>
<version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<!-- External dependencies -->

-<dependency>
<groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
<version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
<version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
<version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
<version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- External dependencies in internal repo-->

-<dependency>
<groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
<artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
<version>11.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>---</groupId>
<artifactId>---</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.34</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
<version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
<version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>```
````

Comment: Which is the specific old version that create the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the problem only appears on your computer, delete the local repository (usually in your user directory under `.m2/repository`) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the code has been conflicting with other dependencies. After I have downloaded only those specific ones, it stopped conflicting.